# Format $_GET variable in url for Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework and it has a controller formatted to be accessed like this: url/search/Steve where Steve is a $_GET variable(name=keyword). It parses it correctly.

Now, the big question is: how can I have an url like that after the form is submitted? Instead of having ?keyword=Steve.

Thanks

Comment: The ZF URL parameters which go into the path part like that are **not** GET variables. They are usually called url parameters or just parameters. For a parameter to be a GET parameter, it needs to go into the query string part of the URL - not the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the getParam method for Zend_Controller_Request

Something like this...

```
$var = Zend_Controller_Request::getParam('keyword');
$url = 'url/search'.$var;
```

If you var_dump($var) in between the two lines of code above you can test what values your application is returning.

This is all part of Zends Request object

Remember you can still use the $_GET superglobal with zend so the above becomes

```
$var=$_GET['keyword'];
$url = 'url/search'.$var;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you really want to have done.

If you have forms then what you should do in your case is to put method="POST" so that the fields don't end up in the URL at all in your case.

Or you need to do some JavaScript trickery to change the action="" of the form whenever the field you mention is changed. However, I've found this to be a bit unreliable as some browsers doesn't really like this for some reason.

Or, perhaps better, you could do a redirect after the form is submitted, where you redirect to the new "prettier" URL.

It all depends on your purpose.